Using \boxplot calculated whisker values to sort outliers
I'm working on getting the \boxplot command from the 'statistics' package to calcualte the lower and upper whisker values of a data set read from a sinlge colum .txt file then use those whisker values to define a range, \minvalue and \maxvalue that can be used with a conditional structure to sort outlier data points from the original data set. I've got the \boxplot command to calculate the whisker and quartile values and preserve them with \xdef, so they can be used outside the \tikzpicture environment, but when I try to pass \minvalue and \maxvalue, along with the original data set to a \foreach loop that uses the 'xfp' package for floating point evaluation it doesn't work...The data in \checklist should be the data read in from data_0.txt, rather than the hardcoded values in \checklist.
Data File (data_0.txt) 10.2 12.5 8.7 10.3 9.8 13.1 10.9 14.7 9.4 12.0 28.0 -2.2
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
     


\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\usepackage{xifthen}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{geometry}   
\geometry{
    left=20mm,
    right=20mm}


\usepackage{float} % For the [H] option
%\usepackage{filecontents}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18} % Adjust the compatibility version as needed
\usepackage{tikz}

% Load the statistics library for boxplot
\usetikzlibrary{pgfplots.statistics}

\usepackage{pgffor} % For the \foreach loop
\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{xfp} % For floating-point evaluation


\begin{document}
    
    
    \begin{figure}[H]
        \begin{center}
            \caption{Boxplot with Median Value Printed. Data File: \texttt{data\_0.txt}}
            \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
                \begin{axis}[
                    grid=both,
                    boxplot,
                    ymin=0, ymax=5,
                    ]
                    \addplot[
                    boxplot,
                    fill=orange,
                    thick
                    ] table[y index = 0]{data_0.txt} 
                    [above]
                    node at (boxplot box cs:\boxplotvalue{median},2)
                    {Median \pgfmathprintnumber{\boxplotvalue{median}}
                        \xdef\med{\boxplotvalue{median}}
                        \xdef\uq{\boxplotvalue{upper quartile}}
                        \xdef\lq{\boxplotvalue{lower quartile}}
                        \xdef\uw{\boxplotvalue{upper whisker}}
                        \xdef\lw{\boxplotvalue{lower whisker}}
                        \xdef\av{\boxplotvalue{average}}
                        \xdef\minvalue{\boxplotvalue{lower whisker}}
                        \xdef\maxvalue{\boxplotvalue{upper whisker}}};
                \end{axis}
            \end{tikzpicture}
        \end{center}
    \end{figure}

\underline{\textbf{Boxplot Statistics:}}

Median: \pgfmathprintnumber{\med}

Upper Quartile: \pgfmathprintnumber{\uq} 

Lower Quartile: \pgfmathprintnumber[fixed, precision=3]{\lq} 

Upper Whisker: \pgfmathprintnumber[fixed, precision=3]{\uw} 

Lower Whisker: \pgfmathprintnumber[fixed, precision=3]{\lw} 
    
Min Value: \pgfmathprintnumber[fixed, precision=3]{\minvalue}   

Max Value: \pgfmathprintnumber[fixed, precision=3]{\maxvalue}   


% Define a list of numbers to check
\def\checklist{2.6, 7.3, 17.3, 5.0, 10.0, 9.35, 8.5, 11.2, 6.7}

minvalue = \minvalue \par
maxvalue = \maxvalue \par

% Iterate over the checklist
\foreach \currentline in \checklist {
    currentline = \currentline \par
    
    \ifnum\fpeval{\currentline > \minvalue} = 1
    \currentline{} is greater than \texttt{minvalue} \par%
    \ifnum\fpeval{\currentline < \maxvalue} = 1
    \currentline{} Less than \texttt{maxvalue} \par \textcolor{blue}{In Range \minvalue{} to \pgfmathprintnumber[fixed, precision=3]{\maxvalue} } \par
    \else
    \currentline{} is greater than \texttt{maxvalue} \par \textcolor{green}{Out of range} \par
    \fi
    \else
    Less than \texttt{minvalue} \par \currentline{} \textcolor{red}{Out of range \minvalue{} to \maxvalue} \par
    \fi
    \par
}

\end{document}


1. Wrong tool?
As I read it library pgfplots.statistics provides drawing commands for statistics, but doesn't do the calculations.
The state-of-the-art tool to use would be R. E.g. entering on the command line of a R-shell:
> x <- c(10.2, 12.5, 8.7, 10.3, 9.8, 13.1, 10.9, 14.7, 9.4, 12.0, 28.0, -2.2)
> quantile(x)
   0%   25%   50%   75%  100% 
-2.20  9.70 10.60 12.65 28.00 
> par(mfrow=c(1,2))
> qqnorm(x)
> boxplot(x)

results in

From the qqnorm plot you see roughly a normal distribution for values below, say, 16, and a difference above, which you might call outliers; same when x is below say 7. In fact your data set has just 1 of it, and Rs boxplot show this, too:
> x[x>15]
[1] 28
> x[x<8]
[1] -2.2
> 

For the R-syntax:

quantile uses the standard quantiles, but you can use any other set
par(mfrow=c(1,2)) tells R to plot the next two graphic commands in a 1-row 2-col window
x[x>15] lists all data from x, where its content is larger than 15

Selecting the good-range without outliers into variable y results in:
> x[x>8][x<16]
 [1] 10.2 12.5  8.7 10.3  9.8 13.1 10.9 14.7  9.4 12.0   NA
> y<-x[x>8][x<16]
> qqnorm(y)
> boxplot(y)


2. Using R with LaTeX
Kindly check out tag R on this site.
3. Violin-plot
There's a new package on ctan which may be a bit more visual than the old boxplot:

from Wikipedia
From said package:

